# How to *un*-alphabetize the Methods & Fields in Visual Studio (2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, alphabetized, vs-classview

I use Java Eclipse and I like how I can toggle between Sorted/Unsorted view of the methods and fields. Unsorted makes it easier to navigate the Source code as-is.

However, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't allow unsorted view intutively in its Class View pane.
Instead, it has other ways to sort:

Does anyone know how to put the Class View in unsorted view?

Comment: What you're looking for isn't achievable in the Class View, but there are VS Extensions like the Productivity Power Tools with it's enhanced scroll bar that can help you out a bit.  You can also change the sorting by right clicking in the class view and choosing a different order, but not "as defined in source code".

Comment: Thanks Agent_9191, I'll take a look into VS Extensions when I get the chance. Yes, I could change the sorting, but not to what I need, like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the new features of VSCommands to do something similar - display the methods / fields / properties as they appear in the code file with the [File Structure](http://vscommands.com/releasenotes/3.7.0.0) window.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great tool, but it's buggy! It crashed visual studio twice.  :(

Comment: @nvsvictor, File Structure has been released for the first time last week and I'm working on stabilising it for the next release (due end of May). I would appreciate if you could send me crash details to support@vscommands.com (what type of file were you browsing c#/c++/vb, what action caused the crash). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, will do. I'm happy that you created this add-on, otherwise it'll drive me nuts. Alphabetizing is so anti-helpful in certain cases!!!